# Calculator always showing 0

Tags: android, decimal, calculator

I've put a calculator into my application but for some reason whatever I do the first number is always zero so if I clicked 1 it shows 01, it does not do this for the result instead it shows the result with .0 on the end, these are both issues for me as I'm definitely a beginner and need this calculator to be as basic and simple as possible.

I read that .0 is a 'double' issue but I cannot workout how to get rid of either of the two problems. Can anybody shed some light on this for me? Here is my code.

```
public class CalcActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener {
private EditText Scr;
private float NumberBf;
private String Operation;
private ButtonClickListener btnClick;
private TextToSpeech myTTS;
private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc);
    Scr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Scr.setEnabled(false);
    btnClick = new ButtonClickListener();
    Button speakButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speak);
    speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
    checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    myTTS= new TextToSpeech(this,this);
    startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);


    int idList[] =  
                     {R.id.button0,R.id.button1,R.id.button2,R.id.button3,
R.id.button4,
R.id.button5,R.id.button6,R.id.button7,
R.id.button8,R.id.button9,R.id.buttonDot,
R.id.buttonAdd,R.id.buttonSub,R.id.buttonMul,
R.id. buttonDiv,R.id.buttonEq,R.id.buttonC
  };

    for(int id:idList){
        View v =(View) findViewById(id);
        v.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    }
}




public void mMath(String str){
    NumberBf = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
    Operation = str;
    Scr.setText("0");
}
public void getKeyboard(String str){
    String ScrCurrent = Scr.getText().toString();
    ScrCurrent += str;
    Scr.setText(ScrCurrent);

}
public void mResult() {
    float NumAf = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
    float result = 0;
    if(Operation.equals("+")){
        result = NumAf + NumberBf;
    }
    if(Operation.equals("-")){
        result = NumberBf - NumAf;
    }
    if(Operation.equals("*")){
        result = NumAf * NumberBf;
    }
    if(Operation.equals("/")){
        result = NumberBf / NumAf;
    }
Scr.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    //get the text entered
    EditText enteredText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String words = enteredText.getText().toString();
    speakWords(words);
}
private void speakWords(String speech) {
    //speak straight away
    myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        }
        else {Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
            installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installTTSIntent);
        }
    }
}
public void onInit(int initStatus) {
    //check for successful instantiation
    if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
            myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    }
    else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...",                

 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}



private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonC:
                Scr.setText("0");
                NumberBf = 0;
                Operation = "";
                break;
            case R.id.buttonAdd:
                mMath("+");
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSub:
                mMath("-");
                break;
            case R.id.buttonMul:
                mMath("*");
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDiv:
                mMath("/");
                break;
            case R.id.buttonEq:
                mResult();
                break;
            default:
                String numb = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
                getKeyboard(numb);
                break;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You really should be more specific when asking question. Nobody here will have time to look at your long code and look for the problem which isn't very clear to be honest. Where do you click "1"? On keyboard or you have buttons with numbers? Where is this text displayed? What is the name of this EditText which shows this text?

Comment: yes the 1 is a button not the keyboard i apologize i didnt realise how vague i was being but there is only only one edit text that displays it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always calling mMath(_) on the ButtonClickListener and so no matter what button you click it sets it to "0"

```
    public void mMath(String str){
    NumberBf = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
    Operation = str;
    Scr.setText("0");  <--
}
```

Comment: so do i simply leave it blank ie:public void mMath(String str){
    NumberBf = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
    Operation = str;
    Scr.setText("");  
    }

Comment: i was also doing the same in result so changed both Scr.setText("0"); to Scr.setText(""); and the first issue is resolved thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your *.0 at the end* problem, you could use a substring of the result omitting the last two characters, before you call setText();
that is if *str* is your string variable that you use to assign through the Scr.settext method
put this line of code before calling setText:

```
str = str.substring(0,str.length-2);
```

Thus you could overcome your *.0 at the end* problem.

Comment: okay either this didnt work for me or i dont know where to throw it in

Comment: Put it in your *mResult* function **just before** your last Scr.setText statement. Since you are using float methods, answer **will** be in float. This way, you don't need to change that and yet still achieve what you want.